Celing fan problems
I have replaced a old fan with a new led one that has a remote. The wiring is simple white to white and black to black. When I turn the power back on I get no lights or fan. Do I need to replace the switch and if so the box has 3 white wires connected andv3 black wires connected together

It does not work with the remote?  Switches can wear out, but is rare.  More common will be a loose/bad connection, or mistake made in the wiring.  Pictures of the fan/light connections and the switch connections will help.

Read the instructions.  Sometimes the remote will need to connect/matched to the fan before working.  The remote needs the switch(if that is where the power comes from) to be on.

Was the old fan wired the same as the new one? People are forever taling apart connections that were not same color to same color and then matching colors when installing the next thing and causing loads of problems as a result. Pictures of the wiring, at the fan, at the switch, and ideally if you bothered to take it like you should have, at the fan before you took the old one apart.

If the fan has pull chain switches also, you may need to pull the chains because the switches may be in the off position.
